# How to get count of tags and list of tags values in XML response in karate

Tags: xml, response, bdd, karate

My response is below

```
    <List>
     <Fee>
      <Amount>10</Amount>
     </Fee>
     <Fee>
      <Amount>10</Amount>
      <Amount>20</Amount>
     </Fee>
    </List>
```

I would like to get count of Amount tag for each fee. Also list of amounts for each fees.

How to achieve this in karate.

fee1 1 amount tags
Fee2 2 amount tags

Answer (score 0):

```
* def response =
"""
<List>
  <Fee>
    <Amount>10</Amount>
  </Fee>
  <Fee>
    <Amount>10</Amount>
    <Amount>20</Amount>
  </Fee>
</List>
"""
```

You can get an array of all the second amounts using XPath like this:

```
* def amt2 = /List/Fee[2]/Amount
* match karate.sizeOf(amt2) == 2
```

But in Karate, an XPath that returns a single node will not be an array. But you can use some conditional logic:

```
* def amt1 = /List/Fee[1]/Amount
* if (karate.typeOf(amt1) != 'list') amt1 = ([amt1])
* match karate.sizeOf(amt1) == 1
```

Here is how you can write a helper function:

```
* def fun = function(index){ var temp = karate.xmlPath(response, '/List/Fee[' + index + ']/Amount'); return karate.typeOf(temp) == 'list' ? temp : [temp] }
* match fun(1) == ['10']
* match fun(2) == ['10', '20']
```

And please read the docs if any of the above is not clear.

Comment: Thanks for quick reply. I am getting below error karate.typrOf is not a function.

Comment: Also if my fee tag is dynamic , I want to get count of amount tag for each fee .   I don't want to hard code fee[1] like that.    So that I want to consider the fee with more than 1 amount tag for next processing

Comment: @Arun please upgrade. and you can of course write a loop and call `fun(x)` dynamically. I already spent a lot of time on this answer - if you can't make it work, please assume it is not supported in karate. you shouldn't be writing such "clever" tests: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50350442/143475