# What Karate xml embedded expression to match one element in array an ignore the others?

Tags: karate

I have two xml files I want to compare with a match. But I want to use embedded expressions / **only define what I'm looking for in the expected xml file**. I don't want to write specific match for this scenario as I want to have a large scenario outline with many xml files that can be totally unique.

In my example, I'm interested in only matching `Item1` and not any other items. The list can be out of order. How can I achieve this?

My expected xml:

```
<Something>
    <Items>
        <Item1 Code="123">
            <SubItem></SubItem>
        </Item1>
        #ignore
    </Items>
</Something>
```

My actual xml:

```
<Something>
    <Items>
        <Item2 Code="123">
            <SubItem></SubItem>
        </Item2>
        <Item1 Code="123">
            <SubItem></SubItem>
        </Item1>
    </Items>
</Something>
```

EDIT:

I would like to only use fuzzy matching.

I see a case like `#[] bar.bar` in other examples, referencing a def in the karate scenario. But I would like to do `#[] <Item1></<Item1>` so that everything is self contained in the XML file, so that the structure I want to match against is still defined in the xml.

My expected XML would look like this then:

```
<Something>
    <Items>
        #[] <Item1 Code="123">
            <SubItem></SubItem>
        </Item1>
    </Items>
</Something>
```

Where I would hope I could define something like this which says, match that `Items` is an array/collection of elements and `Items` contains this specific element.

```
#[] <Item1 Code="123">
        <SubItem></SubItem>
    </Item1>
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are overcomplicated things. This below will work:

```
* def response =
"""
<Something>
    <Items>
        <Item2 Code="123">
            <SubItem></SubItem>
        </Item2>
        <Item1 Code="123">
            <SubItem></SubItem>
        </Item1>
    </Items>
</Something>
"""
* def item1 = /Something/Items/Item1
* match item1 == <Item1 Code="123"><SubItem></SubItem></Item1>
```

You can even do it in one line:

```
* match /Something/Items/Item1 == <Item1 Code="123"><SubItem></SubItem></Item1>
```

If you have a more complicated case, please ask a new question.

Comment: I want to exclusively use fuzzy matching in XML. Is this possible? Can this be possible? It would ideal if I can keep all my matching inside the XML files exclusively for my use case.

Comment: I added an edit to the question. Thank you

Comment: @visc it may be possible if you convert to JSON or refer to the XML examples in the documentation. I'm sorry I can't help more than this. I personally also disagree that you need a "more generic" way to do this, it causes more trouble than its worth in my experience, for e.g: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54126724/143475

Comment: Except that I have many many permutations. Being able to match xml is important and isn't "over engineering" as your opinion believes. Instead of referring to karate, I would like to put xml directly in a fuzzy match expression. Is that something that can be added to karate?

Comment: And not to sound complaining or over dramatic- it just feels like XML is a second class citizen. There seems to be a lot more focus on json. When in practice there also seems to still be a lot of SOAP xml in enterprise

Comment: @visc I will the first to agree / admit that XML support is not as good as JSON, this is technical - for e.g. in JSON there is no concept of a `root` element. things go downhill from there. for some ideas on how to workaround, read this (and the links onward): https://stackoverflow.com/a/58543843/143475 - and of course contributions and pull-requests are highly welcome